# Im getting Error:Tenant admin is disabled for the bot in ms teams

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Bot through teams facing issue:Where i get the error as mentioned below.
Tenant admin is disabled after onSendActivity is invoked through teams.
The below issue happens randomly not always.

[image]

Comment: Has your bot been deployed to multiple tenants? Could it be that one of the tenants is blocking this bot.

Comment: The issue seems to be not occurring now.But i would still want to know the root cause.How do i check whether the bot is deployed to multiple or single tenant?

Comment: Is the bot serivce deployed in European region ?

Comment: yes subhasish.Bot is deployed in european region,erarlier we had issue with typing animation for bot in teams for european region?Anything of that sort happened on 27th of april?

Comment: Yes, There was some issue in Europe. Can you please confirm if issue still exists?

Comment: No the issue doesn't exist anymore.